# Accessing private route

Tags: angular

Is it possible in Angular 5 to create the "private" route that only can be navigated from. So iser cannot get the view just editing the url(then user must be redirected to 404 page) but only with RouterLink or Router?

Comment: Routeguards is pretty easy. Please post portion of your code if any help neede

Answer (score 1):

You can use so called "Route guards" that allows you to decide if from current view (optionally), given route can be activated or not, and this is what you exactly require.

https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards

Comment: Is there another way to do so without guards?

Comment: @SashaSemanyuk whats wrong with guards? They exists explicitly for that purpose

Comment: As I understand the Gurd is design for the key purpose of checking the authentication before accessing the route. Am I wrong?

Comment: No you are wrong. Its purpose is to decide if navigation is allowed or not based on whatever condition you can imagine - ActivatedRoute in your case. Decision based on condition if user is authenticated/autorized is only one appliance of guard.